# On the decomposition of the first term in a decreasing sequence of sets into a collection of disjoint sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We say that a sequence of sets $E_1,E_2,\ldots$ decreases to $E$, if $E_k\supseteq E_{k+1}$ for all $k$, and
$$E=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k.$$

Let $G_k=E_k-E_{k+1}$ for each $k$. Then my textbook told me that
$$E_1=E\cup\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty G_k.$$
But I think the result should be
$$E_1=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty G_k$$
instead. Why's that? The notion of limits in set operations really confuses me, and I cannot come up with a counterexample to show the indispensability of $E$. By the way, does $E_n=(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ help? In this case, the union of $G_k$ is seemingly identical to $E_1$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in E$ then $x\in E_1$ but for every $k$ we have $x\notin E_k-E_{k+1}=G_k$ hence $x\notin\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k$.

So if $E\neq\varnothing$ then $E_1\neq\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k$.

Comment: In my example, $E=\{0\}\neq\phi$, but $E_1=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k$.

Comment: In your example $0\in E_1$. But for which $k$ then do we have $0\in G_k$?...

Answer (score 2):

Well you can see that $G_k\cap E=\emptyset$ since $E\subseteq E_{k+1}$ and $G_k\cap E_{k+1}=\emptyset$ for all $k$. Thus $\bigcup G_k\cap E=\emptyset$, and if $E\neq \emptyset$ your equality fails.

Answer (score 1):

I think is always useful to think on circles insteads of sets... like if every $E_k$ was a circle. Then, the interpretation of the limit of sets is like circles with the same center which ratio is decreasing until some point. For example, consider each $E_k$ as the circles with center on some point $\bar{c}$ (constant) and radius $4+ \frac{1}{k}$, i.e
$$E_k= \{\bar{x}\text{ } |\text{ } ||\bar{x}-\bar{c}||\leq (4+ \frac{1}{k})\}$$

It easy to see that the limit of those sets as $n$ goes to infinity is the circle with center $\bar{c}$ and radius $4$.

Every $G_k$ is the strip between contiguous circles. Then $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty G_k$ is the union of all the strips between contiguous circles except except the limit set. Then, of course the first set, $E_1$, has to contain the limit set.